# View.GONE does not work on "Constraint.Group" specific children

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm experimenting with `"Constraint.Group"` and I've children views: A, B, C.

In code, `"Constraint.Group".visibility = View.Gone` does work, but if I choose to do `A.visibility = View.Gone` it does not take an effect on children view. Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Could you please post your code so we can better understand what's your problem? (Or give concrete exemples)

Comment: post your xml file

Comment: i have the same observation. If i define a Group and then hide a specific view, the view is still shown if the group has undefined visibility in XML.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update:** The behavior of individual view visibility within a group has been change and is reported as fixed in ConstraintLayout version 2.0.0 beta 6. See [bug fixes for ConstraintLayout 2.0.0 beta 6](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/05/constraintlayout-200-beta-6.html) .

---

It does look like group visibility trumps the visibility of individual views of the group. This makes sense since each view has some visibility defined (`GONE`, `VISIBLE`, `INVISIBLE`) so, if an individual view's visibility setting was honored, the integrity of the group would be violated. In other words, the individual view we changed the visibility of would, in essence, not be part of the group.

Comment: Woah I spend like 2 hours on this today. But reading this comment now I at least see the logic behind it 

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Cheticamp and would like to add that you've got to toggle visibility individually as he said, or either create a general group to change all views inside and a local group to change only a specific view, like below:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    />

<android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/group1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view1,view2" />

<android.support.constraint.Group
        android:id="@+id/group2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="view1" />
```

It won't be possible to change a single view visibility that is inside a group, but this way you can change group1 visibility or group2 visibility.

Comment: That will work but then all benefit from using Groups are gone (

Answer (score 1):

If you use above 2 version of constraint layout, you should use isGone property.
`group.isGone = true`
But if you use version lower than 2, it doesn't work due to some bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look inside the source code of ConstraintLayout:

[image]

Looks like ConstraintLayout will take out `visibility` and `elevation` of its child view, and rebind those value back to the child view itself.

So setting visibility to child view inside Group is not working.

Some workaround would be referencing single view to another Group (it might look tricky but still acceptable to me).